# Using Recursion for Subset Summation?

Tags: java, recursion

I have been stumped on a question in my java class and so have my colleges. I'm asking for some pointers, because i'm lost as to where to start. Our assignment asks to take the input "  positive integers along with a list of target values and determines how many subsets of the input integers, if any, sum up to each given target value."
If we have the input:

2 3 4 5

1

4

5

Our output should be:
0

1

2

I understand this, and have an idea how to do this, but i'm lost on two points.

## 1, we must use recursion for this, #2, we have basic code provided. All i need is some help understanding how to use the skeleton code. I want to solve it on my own. A small example using the code or a tiny fraction of what is needed will be helpful!

Thank you!

Code given:

```
static int subsets( int[] a, int n, int target) {

// add your code here
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

int a[] = new int[1000];


Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner setScanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());

    int n=0;
    while( setScanner.hasNextInt() ) {
    a[n] = setScanner.nextInt();
    n++;
    if(n>1000) {
        System.out.println( "Too many integers!" );
        return;
    }
    }

    while( scanner.hasNextInt() ) {
    int target = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println( subsets(a, n, target) );
}

}
```

}

Comment: Some formatting would help

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a homework problem, I won't give you any code; instead, I'll give you a few pointers (as in hints, not pointers as in `C` pointers)

The problem lies in determining the number of subsets summing up to the number. So, what you can do is define a function with the array and the sum as parameters. Loop through each element in the array, and pass the following parameters into this same function again: the array WITHOUT the current element, and the `sum - current_element`. I'll leave it up to you to determine how to stop.

HINT:

> When the sum is less than zero, it means that there is a subset that sums to the correct value. You'll want to increase a global value by one. When the sum is less than zero, it means that the last value failed, and you will want to stop recursing.

Another problem: `scanner.hasNextInt()` does not work as you expect. What you want to do is find `n`, and then the elements of the array.

Your first line should then be `int number_of_elements = scanner.nextInt()`. This variable represents the number of elements in the array.

Then, you want to read an integer `number_of_elements` times. So, something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++) {
    // Read another number
}
```

That way, you can initialise `a` as `int[] a = new int[number_of_elements]`, so your array will be just the right length. With this method, you will only need one scanner, *and* your array can be as long as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I have a question about your explanation, so when you say define a function, we're given the function static int subsets( int[] a, int n, int target) { to work with, do I make a function within a function? Or do I use the one given?

Comment: @Kajamaz You would just use the one given. It is impossible to make nested functions in Java.

Comment: Ok thanks. So, you say to loop through each element, but that's what i'm lost at. I have done binary searches before. Is that what we're trying to do here? I keep pressing enter by accident. So, from what i wanna do, please tell me if i'm wrong, make an if statement that checks if n<0.

Comment: @Kajamaz A binary search isn't what you want here. You just want a basic `for` loop here, looping from `0` to `n`.

Comment: I was about to ask you a question about the for loop, i really appreciate it. I saw your answer, I was about to give the same exact code ! The only difference is that for number of elements i'd use a.length?

Comment: Well, in your code, you have `a = new int[1000]`, so `a.length` will always equal `1000`.

Answer (score 0):

The point of recursive algorithms is to make the problem smaller and use the result of the smaller problem(s) to solve the large one, so when subsets(a, n, target) is called it should do just that.

a is current array
n is the number of numbers in the array
target is the target.

the first thing to do is to check if all the numbers in a adds up to the target

then it need to know if any of the subsets matches the target. Who better then to ask then itself with a modified a and n.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. You're restating the question and the obvious, and the last block does not help at all.

Comment: Ya, I guess I'm tiered and rambling on a bit. But its hard to know what is obvious to a student and I didn't want to say to much to soon. Looks like you guys have it under control.

Comment: @Bear But the part about the point of recursive algorithms was well explained. I won't vote on it.